# How should we improve the website speed?

Tags: cdn

We are OK with the current performance but for the past 2-3 weeks, Google search console shows that none of the pages are indexed. Its actually indexed though.

https://www.softwareproductguide.com/

Kindly guide us on how to proceed.
1. Should we change webhosting provided?
2. Should we get a good CDN service?
3. Should we change the theme as the site speed is poor too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use a cdn, and optimize it to provide the cached version of the pages. Also you should work on your theme to optimize the LCP, FCP, CLS

Answer (score 1):

There are few elements to getting fast website, and I have run some tests with your website:

1. Loading time is 3-4 seconds on average, which is slow, but not too slow. Some of that can will improve with the use of CDN for images, JS and CSS files, maybe 20-40% faster page loading time.
2. Slow response time (initial response is well over 1 second), is due to the hosting. If you use shared hosting, you can try and switch to some better hosting (I can suggest SiteGround).
3. But, you can also try to use some WordPress cache plugins. Using cache plugins adds two important elements: setup for browser cache use and caching of page content for faster loading.
4. The theme is not a big part of the slow loading from what I can see.
5. PHP version used is a big part of the loading speed. PHP 7 and PHP 7.1 are much faster then PHP 5.3 to 5.6, so if your hosting supports it, switch to PHP 7.

So, my advice is to start using some WordPress cache plugin (WP-Rocket is the best, but it is not free, you can use WP Super Cache plugin, it is free). Get a CDN account and set it up with the cache plugin (all cache plugins support the use of CDN). That would result in at least 50-60% better load times.

But, if that doesn't happen, then your hosting is a problem, and then you can think of changing hosting.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation Milan. It was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think everything is OK with performance, your website loads fast enough for me. You can try to install WP-Super-Cache plugin - it will improve speed and reduce server load.

If pages are actually in Google index, it is OK, they could appear in Search Console after certain amount of time.

Comment: Always welcome :) click on the Up Vote (arrow top), it will be really appreciated

Comment: Yes. I already did that. Since I am new to forum its not displayed yet. Good luck!